# Remove Two sets of curly brackets from output

Tags: output-formatting

My output for my "c" values is given in two sets of curly brackets, how can I remove these? I need to be able to take a "c" value and test whether it is positive or negative.
Also how can I speed up my code? Thank you!

Description of what I am doing:
Hello, I am running a for loop to solve equations with some specified parameters (α, γ, Fa, Fb,...) and two others (μ, g) varying on a matrix of values (μGMat) and then taking the solved "c" values and building a matrix for them called myCaValss and myCbValss.

What I want:
(I would also want to make a version of my code where it only takes positive values of cA and cB and only builds a matrix of positive values. but this is not urgent.)

```
μGMat={{0.01,0.01},{0.02,0.01},{0.03,0.01},{0.04,0.01},{0.05,0.01},{0.06,0.01},{0.07,0.01},{0.08,0.01},{0.09,0.01},{0.1,0.01},{0.01,0.02},{0.02,0.02},{0.03,0.02},{0.04,0.02},{0.05,0.02},{0.06,0.02},{0.07,0.02},{0.08,0.02},{0.09,0.02},{0.1,0.02},{0.01,0.03},{0.02,0.03},{0.03,0.03},{0.04,0.03},{0.05,0.03},{0.06,0.03},{0.07,0.03},{0.08,0.03},{0.09,0.03},{0.1,0.03},{0.01,0.04},{0.02,0.04},{0.03,0.04},{0.04,0.04},{0.05,0.04},{0.06,0.04},{0.07,0.04},{0.08,0.04},{0.09,0.04},{0.1,0.04},{0.01,0.05},{0.02,0.05},{0.03,0.05},{0.04,0.05},{0.05,0.05},{0.06,0.05},{0.07,0.05},{0.08,0.05},{0.09,0.05},{0.1,0.05},{0.01,0.06},{0.02,0.06},{0.03,0.06},{0.04,0.06},{0.05,0.06},{0.06,0.06},{0.07,0.06},{0.08,0.06},{0.09,0.06},{0.1,0.06},{0.01,0.07},{0.02,0.07},{0.03,0.07},{0.04,0.07},{0.05,0.07},{0.06,0.07},{0.07,0.07},{0.08,0.07},{0.09,0.07},{0.1,0.07},{0.01,0.08},{0.02,0.08},{0.03,0.08},{0.04,0.08},{0.05,0.08},{0.06,0.08},{0.07,0.08},{0.08,0.08},{0.09,0.08},{0.1,0.08},{0.01,0.09},{0.02,0.09},{0.03,0.09},{0.04,0.09},{0.05,0.09},{0.06,0.09},{0.07,0.09},{0.08,0.09},{0.09,0.09},{0.1,0.09},{0.01,0.1},{0.02,0.1},{0.03,0.1},{0.04,0.1},{0.05,0.1},{0.06,0.1},{0.07,0.1},{0.08,0.1},{0.09,0.1},{0.1,0.1}};

α = 0.25;
γ  = 0;

xm = 148;
x0 = 145;

Fa = 6;
Fb = 6;

myCaValss={};
myCbValss = {};

For[i=1,i<101,i++,

cA[i_]:=NSolve[Reduce[1+R*c==R*Exp[-M]*(1-S*Exp[(1+R*c)*M]/(R*c+1+S))]/.{R->(π*α^2*Fa)/Part[μGMat,i,1],S-> γ/Part[μGMat,i,1],M->Part[μGMat,i,1](xm-x0)/Part[μGMat,i,2]},c,Reals] ;   
 
cB[i_]:=NSolve[Reduce[1+R*c==R*Exp[-M]*(1-S*Exp[(1+R*c)*M]/(R*c+1+S))]/.{R->(π*α^2*Fb)/Part[μGMat,i,1],S->γ/Part[μGMat,i,1],M->Part[μGMat,i,1](xm-x0)/Part[μGMat,i,2]},c,Reals];

AppendTo[myCaValss,{Part[μGMat,i,1],Part[μGMat,i,2],cA[i]}];

AppendTo[myCbValss,{Part[μGMat,i,1],Part[μGMat,i,2],cB[i]}]]

MatrixForm[myCaValss]
MatrixForm[myCbValss]
```

This gives me an output of :

```
(0.01   0.01    {{c->0.0412988}}
0.02    0.01    {{c->-0.0169765},{c->-0.0144978}}
0.03    0.01    {{c->-0.0254648},{c->-0.0253414}}
0.04    0.01    {{c->-0.0339531},{c->-0.0339469}}
0.05    0.01    {{c->-0.0424413},{c->-0.042441}}
0.06    0.01    {{c->-0.0509296},{c->-0.0509296}}
0.07    0.01    {{c->-0.0594178},{c->-0.0594178}}
0.08    0.01    {}
0.09    0.01    {}
0.1 0.01    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0848826}}
0.01    0.02    {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.214642}}
0.02    0.02    {{c->-0.0169765},{c->0.0328105}}
0.03    0.02    {{c->-0.0254648},{c->-0.0143558}}
0.04    0.02    {{c->-0.0339531},{c->-0.0314743}}
0.05    0.02    {{c->-0.0424413},{c->-0.0418882}}
0.06    0.02    {{c->-0.0509296},{c->-0.0508062}}
0.07    0.02    {{c->-0.0594178},{c->-0.0593903}}
0.08    0.02    {{c->-0.0679061},{c->-0.0679}}
0.09    0.02    {{c->-0.0763944},{c->-0.076393}}
0.1 0.02    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0848823}}
0.01    0.03    {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.359391}}
0.02    0.03    {{c->0.118359}}
0.03    0.03    {{c->0.0243223}}
0.04    0.03    {{c->-0.0339531},{c->-0.0156374}}
0.05    0.03    {{c->-0.0424413},{c->-0.0357034}}
0.06    0.03    {{c->-0.0509296},{c->-0.0484508}}
0.07    0.03    {{c->-0.0594178},{c->-0.058506}}
0.08    0.03    {{c->-0.0679061},{c->-0.0675706}}
0.09    0.03    {{c->-0.0763944},{c->-0.076271}}
0.1 0.03    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0848372}}
0.01    0.04    {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.463878}}
0.02    0.04    {{c->-0.0169765},{c->0.206154}}
0.03    0.04    {{c->-0.0254648},{c->0.0799344}}
0.04    0.04    {{c->-0.0339531},{c->0.015834}}
0.05    0.04    {{c->-0.0424413},{c->-0.0189236}}
0.06    0.04    {{c->-0.0509296},{c->-0.0398206}}
0.07    0.04    {{c->-0.0594178},{c->-0.0541703}}
0.08    0.04    {{c->-0.0679061},{c->-0.0654274}}
0.09    0.04    {{c->-0.0763944},{c->-0.0752235}}
0.1 0.04    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0843296}}
0.01    0.05    {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.540323}}
0.02    0.05    {{c->-0.0169765},{c->0.284218}}
0.03    0.05    {{c->-0.0254648},{c->0.139834}}
0.04    0.05    {{c->0.0567649}}
0.05    0.05    {{c->-0.0424413},{c->0.00734575}}
0.06    0.05    {{c->-0.0509296},{c->-0.0236059}}
0.07    0.05    {{c->-0.0594178},{c->-0.0444223}}
0.08    0.05    {{c->-0.0596764}}
0.09    0.05    {{c->-0.0763944},{c->-0.0718778}}
0.1 0.05    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0824039}}
0.01    0.06    {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.598042}}
0.02    0.06    {{c->-0.0169765},{c->0.350903}}
0.03    0.06    {{c->-0.0254648},{c->0.197665}}
0.04    0.06    {{c->-0.0339531},{c->0.101382}}
0.05    0.06    {{c->0.0396437}}
0.06    0.06    {{c->-0.0509296},{c->-0.00114251}}
0.07    0.06    {{c->-0.0594178},{c->-0.0292205}}
0.08    0.06    {{c->-0.0495905}}
0.09    0.06    {{c->-0.0763944},{c->-0.0652854}}
0.1 0.06    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0781447}}
0.01    0.07    {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.642951}}
0.02    0.07    {{c->-0.0169765},{c->0.407396}}
0.03    0.07    {{c->-0.0254648},{c->0.250988}}
0.04    0.07    {{c->-0.0339531},{c->0.146139}}
0.05    0.07    {{c->-0.0424413},{c->0.0748778}}
0.06    0.07    {{c->0.0254967}}
0.07    0.07    {{c->-0.0594178},{c->-0.00963078}}
0.08    0.07    {{c->-0.0679061},{c->-0.0354729}}
0.09    0.07    {{c->-0.0552661}}
0.1 0.07    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0711188}}
0.01    0.08    {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.678801}}
0.02    0.08    {{c->-0.0169765},{c->0.45539}}
0.03    0.08    {{c->0.299188}}
0.04    0.08    {{c->-0.0339531},{c->0.189177}}
0.05    0.08    {{c->-0.0424413},{c->0.110914}}
0.06    0.08    {{c->0.0544696}}
0.07    0.08    {{c->0.0130219}}
0.08    0.08    {{c->-0.0679061},{c->-0.018119}}
0.09    0.08    {{c->-0.0763944},{c->-0.0421763}}
0.1 0.08    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0613649}}
0.01    0.09    {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.708043}}
0.02    0.09    {{c->-0.0169765},{c->0.496441}}
0.03    0.09    {{c->-0.0254648},{c->0.342415}}
0.04    0.09    {{c->-0.0339531},{c->0.229644}}
0.05    0.09    {{c->0.146434}}
0.06    0.09    {{c->-0.0509296},{c->0.0844057}}
0.07    0.09    {{c->-0.0594178},{c->0.0375541}}
0.08    0.09    {{c->-0.0679061},{c->0.00157734}}
0.09    0.09    {{c->-0.0763944},{c->-0.0266073}}
0.1 0.09    {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0492086}}
0.01    0.1 {{c->-0.00848826},{c->0.73233}}
0.02    0.1 {{c->-0.0169765},{c->0.531835}}
0.03    0.1 {{c->-0.0254648},{c->0.381105}}
0.04    0.1 {{c->-0.0339531},{c->0.267241}}
0.05    0.1 {{c->0.180689}}
0.06    0.1 {{c->-0.0509296},{c->0.114369}}
0.07    0.1 {{c->-0.0594178},{c->0.0630386}}
0.08    0.1 {{c->0.0228118}}
0.09    0.1 {{c->-0.0763944},{c->-0.00918886}}
0.1 0.1 {{c->-0.0848826},{c->-0.0350956}}

)
```

Where the "c" values are in two sets of curly brackets. How can I fix this?
My code also takes a good half hour to run, is there any way to speed it up?
Thank you.

Comment: When you do the `AppendTo`, use `Flatten`, e.g `AppendTo[myCaValss, Flatten[{Part[\[Mu]GMat, i, 1], Part[\[Mu]GMat, i, 2], cA[i]}]];` Also if you don't want the rules like `c->0.118359` but just want numbers, then add `c /.` in front of your `NSolve`'s.

Comment: The poor performance is because you're repeatedly reducing and `NSolve`-ing. You probably don't need the `Reduce` in there - you could move it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should take care of some of the performance issues. You were doing `Reduce` in the `NSolve` unnecessarily and defining functions in the loop. Also you can use `Table` or better `ParallelTable` to build up the lists which is more efficient than using `AppendTo` here. It now takes < 10 seconds on my machine. Also, sometimes there are no solutions, or only one solution given by `NSolve` which is why the `MatrixForm`'s below do not produce a proper matrix. Let me know if this is a problem:

```
μGMat = {{0.01, 0.01}, {0.02, 0.01}, {0.03, 0.01}, {0.04, 0.01}, {0.05, 0.01}, {0.06, 0.01}, {0.07, 0.01}, {0.08, 0.01}, {0.09, 0.01}, {0.1, 0.01}, {0.01, 0.02}, {0.02, 0.02}, {0.03, 0.02}, {0.04, 0.02}, {0.05, 0.02}, {0.06, 0.02}, {0.07, 0.02}, {0.08, 0.02}, {0.09, 0.02}, {0.1, 0.02}, {0.01, 0.03}, {0.02, 0.03}, {0.03, 0.03}, {0.04, 0.03}, {0.05, 0.03}, {0.06, 0.03}, {0.07, 0.03}, {0.08, 0.03}, {0.09, 0.03}, {0.1, 0.03}, {0.01, 0.04}, {0.02, 0.04}, {0.03, 0.04}, {0.04, 0.04}, {0.05, 0.04}, {0.06, 0.04}, {0.07, 0.04}, {0.08, 0.04}, {0.09, 0.04}, {0.1, 0.04}, {0.01, 0.05}, {0.02, 0.05}, {0.03, 0.05}, {0.04, 0.05}, {0.05, 0.05}, {0.06, 0.05}, {0.07, 0.05}, {0.08, 0.05}, {0.09, 0.05}, {0.1, 0.05}, {0.01, 0.06}, {0.02, 0.06}, {0.03, 0.06}, {0.04, 0.06}, {0.05, 0.06}, {0.06, 0.06}, {0.07, 0.06}, {0.08, 0.06}, {0.09, 0.06}, {0.1, 0.06}, {0.01, 0.07}, {0.02, 0.07}, {0.03, 0.07}, {0.04, 0.07}, {0.05, 0.07}, {0.06, 0.07}, {0.07, 0.07}, {0.08, 0.07}, {0.09, 0.07}, {0.1, 0.07}, {0.01, 0.08}, {0.02, 0.08}, {0.03, 0.08}, {0.04, 0.08}, {0.05, 0.08}, {0.06, 0.08}, {0.07, 0.08}, {0.08, 0.08}, {0.09, 0.08}, {0.1, 0.08}, {0.01, 0.09}, {0.02, 0.09}, {0.03, 0.09}, {0.04, 0.09}, {0.05, 0.09}, {0.06, 0.09}, {0.07, 0.09}, {0.08, 0.09}, {0.09, 0.09}, {0.1, 0.09}, {0.01, 0.1}, {0.02, 0.1}, {0.03,0.1}, {0.04, 0.1}, {0.05, 0.1}, {0.06, 0.1}, {0.07, 0.1}, {0.08, 0.1}, {0.09, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.1}};
α = 0.25;
γ = 0;
xm = 148;
x0 = 145;
Fa = 6;
Fb = 6;
eqn = Reduce[1 + R*c == R*Exp[-M]*(1 - S*Exp[(1 + R*c)*M]/(R*c + 1 + S))];
cFn[i_,Fn_] := NSolve[eqn /. {
     R -> (π*α^2*Fn)/μGMat[[i, 1]], 
     S -> γ/μGMat[[i, 1]], 
     M -> μGMat[[i, 1]] (xm - x0)/μGMat[[i, 2]]},
     c, Reals];
myCaValss = ParallelTable[Join[μGMat[[i, 1 ;; 2]], Flatten@cFn[i,Fa]], {i, 100}];
myCbValss = ParallelTable[Join[μGMat[[i, 1 ;; 2]], Flatten@cFn[i,Fb]], {i, 100}];
MatrixForm[myCaValss]
MatrixForm[myCbValss]
```

---

This will allow you to get the first positive `c` solution for each row, discarding negative `c` and rows with zero solutions:

```
getPositiveC[sol_] := If[Length[sol] == 0, Missing, 
  SelectFirst[Flatten[sol][[All, 2]], # > 0 &]]

myCaValss = 
  Select[ParallelTable[
    Join[μGMat[[i, 1 ;; 2]], {getPositiveC@Flatten@cFn[i, Fa]}], {i, 100}], 
   NumericQ[#[[3]]] &];

myCbValss = 
  Select[ParallelTable[
    Join[μGMat[[i, 1 ;; 2]], {getPositiveC@Flatten@cFn[i, Fb]}], {i, 100}], 
   NumericQ[#[[3]]] &];

MatrixForm[myCaValss]
MatrixForm[myCbValss]
```

Comment: Hi flinty, thank you ! Question: Does the getPositive only look through the "first" c value if there are two?      I am getting a lot of errors when i run the getPositive.  I will eventually need to use each of the positive constants (including any second positive constants) to plug into an equation and make a table of  rBA and rAB values ( my equations, with cA being the constant in rBA and cB being the constant in rAB). Is there an easy way to make it a nice matrix?

Comment: @elcharlosmaster yes, it uses `SelectFirst`. The first one should be the smaller of the two as NSolve would have sorted the solutions when you obtained them. You can't make a nice matrix if  some rows have two solutions while others have a single solution.